# Donation to Tor — problem with anonymity

Tags: anonymity

It appears that the US government has pulled the plug, and Tor now requires donations to carry on. But the problem is, the moment I make a payment through a credit card I am immediately identified as a Tor user, this time by a name and a lot more information than just an IP address.

So my question is: Is it possible to make anonymous donations?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by your second question, but maybe you could move it to a new question and elaborate a bit? In general, try to ask one question per post unless they're closely related. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You won't necessarily be identified as a Tor user if you donate by credit card, only as a Tor supporter: Some people recognize the Tor project as a valuable organization and choose to support it financially, even though they don't use Tor themselves.

One option you have is to donate to an organization which supports Tor. That way, if you use a credit card or Paypal, your donation will be linked to that organization rather that to the Tor Project directly.

The Freedom of the Press Foundation is currently (at the time of writing) collecting donations to "[Support Encryption Tools for Journalists](https://pressfreedomfoundation.org/)". Of four recipient organizations, one is the Tor Project, another is Tails; you can choose how your donation will be divided up.

The Freedom of the Press Foundation also accept [anonymous donations by mail](https://pressfreedomfoundation.org/donation-information).

[Torservers.net](https://www.torservers.net/donate.html) and its member organizations also accept donations by a variety of methods; this money is used to fund fast Tor relays and expand the Tor network.

The above organizations also accept Bitcoin donations, however Bitcoin is not anonymous unless you take adequate precautions.

Comment: Depending on where you live, you may be able to purchase a prepaid credit card (MasterCard or VISA) with cash, and use that to donate to the project.

Answer (score 0):

You should open a cryptocurrency wallet and buy bitcoins or cyptocurrencies with your credit card in cryptocurrency exchanges or through a cryptocurrency ATM (Beware of their higher fees). Then, use a crytocurrency tumbler service like Joinmarket to anonymize your cryptocurrencies and transfer into a new cryptocurrency wallet.

Do take note of the fees and the trustworthiness involved in such tumblers, exchanges and bitcoin ATMs and also of course beware the legalities of cryptocurrency and its' tumblers. Hopefully my answer will help people worldwide, not just in US.

Answer (score -1):

You could consider using a router that has Tor built into it like a PAPARouter. It has Tor hard coded into it and can anonymize several devices at once (Google it). They're cheap too but probably the coolest thing is that they exclude, by default, US and US intelligence friendly exit nodes. Hope this helps.

Comment: This product would raise similar concerns to the "Safeplug" as discussed [here](https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2013-November/031215.html), not least the lack of open source code on their website.